# Moving an object quickly accros the screen using touch in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, game-engine

I'm currently developing a game and I want to allow the player to drag a gameobject across the screen using touch controls. However, for some reason, my code keeps on returning an error('deltaPosition' does not exist in the current context), which shouldn't happen because I got the code from a youtube video where it didn't display any compiling errors when the person showed the code. Is this due to a new version of C# or does someone know how I could solve this problem. Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kTgM.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


    public class PositionTracker : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        float                  _horizontalimit = 2.5f, _verticalLimit = 2.5f, dragSpeed = 0.1f;

        Transform cashedTransform;

        Vector3 startingPos;


        void Start()
        {
            cashedTransform = transform;
            startingPos = cashedTransform.position;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Vector2 deltaPostion = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

                switch (Input.GetTouch(0).phase)
                {
                    case TouchPhase.Began:
                    break;

                    case TouchPhase.Moved:
                        DragObject(deltaPosition);
                        break;

                    case TouchPhase.Ended:
                        break;
                }
            }

            //Debug.Log("target is " + touch.position + " pixels from the left");
        }

        void DragObject(Vector2 deltaPostion)
        {
            cashedTransform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp((deltaPosition.x * dragSpeed) + cashedTransform.position.x,
                startingPos.x - _horizontalimit, startingPos.x + _horizontalimit), 
            Mathf.Clamp((deltaPostion.y * dragSpeed) + cashedTransform.position.y,
            startingPos.y - _verticalLimit, startingPos.y + _verticalLimit),
            cashedTransform.position.z);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full error? It should tell you which line is not working...

Comment: The problem here is due to a typo. Sometimes you are spelling it POSITION and sometimes POSTION.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `deltaPosition` because you named the variable `deltaPostion` hence the error`('deltaPosition' does not exist in the current context)` 
[image]